# MySQL SELECT FROM a relation table WHERE they have the same relatives

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a situation that there is a relation table like this:

```
eaters:

id   name     fruit
1    jack     banana
2    jack     apple
3    jane     banana
4    jane     apple
5    jane     orange
6    richard  banana
7    richard  apple
```

Now, who has ate the same types of fruit as 'Jack'?

For example in above table, 'Richard' is the answer.

The pseudo-query I have in mind is:

```
SELECT name AS the_guy 
FROM eaters 
WHERE 
  (SELECT fruit FROM eaters WHERE name=the_guy) = 
  (SELECT fruit FROM eaters WHERE name='jack')
```

And I don't know if this is even possible in MySQL. For now I fetched the entire table and extract the answer from the result with PHP, which is not a nice approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your expect output? or your query result?

Comment: What you are looking for can be achieved using a Common Table Expression (CTE).  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/

Comment: Just the names. As rows or list. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be using conditional `Group_Concat()` with `Having` clause. We can get all the fruits of `jack` in an ordered comma separated string, within a subquery (Derived Table).

Now, we can get the same ordered list of fruits for other guys, and use `HAVING` clause to consider those `name` values which match the "jack_fruits".

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.name AS the_guy 
FROM eaters AS t1 
JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fruit ORDER BY fruit) AS jack_fruits
      FROM eaters 
      WHERE name = 'jack') AS t2 
WHERE t1.name <> 'jack' 
GROUP BY t1.name 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(t1.fruit ORDER BY fruit) = MAX(t2.jack_fruits );
```

**Result**

```
| the_guy |
| ------- |
| richard |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/21AMga4X7HDRjMnX8tNGRK/0)

Comment: I had to adapt the query to my real table values and that's why it took time. And YES your answer gives the right answer. Thank a lot. Please be patient till stackoverflow allows me to accept this ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

```
SELECT e2.name
FROM   eaters e1
      INNER JOIN eaters e2
              ON e1.fruit = e2.fruit
WHERE  e1.name = 'Jack'
      AND e2.name != 'Jack'
GROUP  BY e2.name
```

Comment: @JamesNickel Glad I could help.

Comment: @JamesNickel this query does not even give the right result, unless you yourself are not clear about the requirements: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/21AMga4X7HDRjMnX8tNGRK/1

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya why doesn't it give the right result?

Comment: @iminiki Run the fiddle. You will get your answer. This query returns jane and richard. While the correct answer as per question is Richard only.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya no, the right answer is Jane and Richard. Read the question again. "who has ate the same types of fruit as 'Jack'?"

Comment: I am reading the full question: "Now, who has ate the same types of fruit as 'Jack'?

For example in above table, 'Richard' is the answer."

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I see what we're disagreeing on. Your query shows the exact set of fruits, mine shows any fruits they've shared.

Comment: GROUP BY, but no set function. Why not SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: @iminiki anyways I have removed my answer. OP itself is unclear what he wants.

Comment: @jarlh that was the first thing that came to my mind. Is there any performance-wise difference between them?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya You deleted your answer before I can see it man. But you're right in the comments.

Comment: I don't know MySQL well enough to answer that question. I just think SELECT DISTINCT makes more sense, if you want a distinct result.

Comment: @JamesNickel I have undeleted the answer. You can check that now

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Please give me some time to test it.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya since the OP posted a positive comment for iminiki's answer, then this is what he wants. The same result is produced by my answer too and I also received a positive comment. Maybe in his question the expected result it wasn't clear enough but if this is what he needs then there's nothing more to argue about.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to understand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM eaters 
WHERE
    name <> 'Jack' 
    AND 
    fruit IN (SELECT fruit FROM eaters WHERE name = 'Jack')
```

Answer (score 1):

better use this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       e.name
FROM eaters e
WHERE name <> 'jack'
      AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           name
    FROM eaters e1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM eaters e2 WHERE e2.name = 'jack' AND e1.fruit = e2.fruit
    )
          AND e1.name = e.name
);
```

Comment: This works. Thank man. I accepted the earlier correct answer. But your answer is simpler and correct too. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Misafer No problem.